# Render component on external action dispatched

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateStore lib :

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
console.log("reducer", state, action.type, action.payload);
switch (action.type) {
case "start":
case "ok": {
  return (function () {
    const targetStName = AVMModel.nextState(state.data.name, action.type);
    postData(state, targetStName);
    return state;
  })();
}
case "payload": {
  console.log("state before payload action", state);
  state = action.payload;
  console.log("state after payload action", state);
  return state;
}
default:
  // throw Error("Action inconnue : " + action.type);
  return state;
}
};
```

As you see when a component dispatch a ok or a start the reducer trigger nextState action on a state machine. This make the state machine asking the backend to publish the new state. A listener listens (yes indeed ;)) to any message from backend (SSE) and onMessage received it dispatches the new state : `dispatch({ type: "payload", payload });`. As indicated in reducer function (see  `case "payload":...`) the state is updated accordingly.
I expect the children components to be updated with the new values from this new state. But nothing happens.
Here is how I propagate the context :

```
const AVMStateContext = createContext(dataForInitialState);
const AVMDispatchContext = createContext(null);

export const AVMProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, dataForInitialState);
   return (
       <AVMDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          <AVMStateContext.Provider value={state}>
              {children}
          </AVMStateContext.Provider>
       </AVMDispatchContext.Provider>
   );
 };
 export const useAVMStateContext = () => {
    return useContext(AVMStateContext);
 };
 export const useAVMDispatchContext = () => {
   return useContext(AVMDispatchContext);
 };
```

And then in a children component (I have other components interested in other aspect of the state) :

```
(...)//some import, REACT and so on 
import gpsGreen from "../assets/gps_up-green.png";
import gpsRed from "../assets/gps_up-red.png";
import gpsYellow from "../assets/gps_up-yellow.png";
import dataGreen from "../assets/4g_up-green.png";
import dataRed from "../assets/4g_up-red.png";
import dataYellow from "../assets/4g_up-yellow.png";
import htcGreen from "../assets/htc_up-green.png";
import htcRed from "../assets/htc_up-red.png";

export const Signals = () => {
const state = useAVMStateContext();
const [color, setColor] = useState({ data: dataGreen, gps: gpsGreen });
const files = {
  green: { gps: gpsGreen, data: dataGreen },
  yellow: { gps: gpsYellow, data: dataYellow },
  red: { gps: gpsRed, data: dataRed },
};
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("useeffect triggered ", state);
  let c = { ...color };
  for (var type in color) {
    c[type] = files.green[type];
    if (state.signals[type] < 5) {
      c[type] = files.yellow[type];
    }
    if (state.signals[type] < 1) {
      c[type] = files.red[type];
    }
    setColor(c);
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
 }, [state]);

return (
<>
  {state.signals.htc ? (
    <img alt="htc" src={htcGreen}></img>
  ) : (
    <img alt="htc" src={htcRed}></img>
  )}

  <img alt="4g" src={color.data}></img>
  <img alt="gps" src={color.gps}></img>
</>
);
};
export default Signals;
```

If I force refresh (F5) I see that images change, but "naturally" nothing changes.
How would you do (to POST a state and having a result asynchronously on another channel and then use it in a component)?

Answer (score 0):

You know what ?
If I add a direct field in my state like time for example : it works !
so I changed to :

```
case "payload": {
  console.log("state before payload action", state);
  state = { ...action.payload };
  console.log("state after payload action", state);
  return state;
}
```

and payload looks like :

```
payload.signals = { GPS: gps, data: data, htc: true };
payload.time = new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
```

time is a new attribute and I think this attribute help React deduce that state has changed... otherwise the changes are too deep inside the payload and can't be "seen". Is that a correct assertion ?